# rails_admin Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed for my app RailsAdmin, but I can't go to the admin panel. After authorization I have routing error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/admin"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

/config/routes.rb

```
1.mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/adminpanel', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
1.RailsAdmin.config do |config|
2.  config.authorize_with :cancan
3.end
```

/app/models/ability.rb

```
1.class Ability
2.  include CanCan::Ability

3.  def initialize(user)
4.    if user.class.to_s == "Admin"
5.        can :access, :rails_admin
6.        can :manage, :all
7.    elsif user.class.to_s == "User"
8.        can :manage, :read
9.    end
10.  end
11.end
```

Also I have Admin model

/app/models/admin.rb

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

But if I add in my routes.rb this:

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

I have cyclic forwarding.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Did you run "rake routes" as suggested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting these two lines at the bottom part of your routes:

> mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/adminpanel', :as => 'rails_admin'
>   root :to => redirect('/adminpanel')